# Android: Foreign Key (want every car have its own record to be save in SQLite)

Tags: android, sqlite, foreign-keys

My android application is about car management.
i will have list of cars and their management like (fuel, traveling, repair).
suppose i have 2 cars in list
i) Honda ABC 123.
ii) Toyota ABC 298.

What should i do to store the records in table (fuel, traveling, repair) of specific car? 
 I tried foreign key in fuel, traveling and repair tables of car table.
but the value of foreign key is null.
 I am confused what to do.

Here is my database 
Car Table

```
     /*
     * ====================================================================
     * TABLE CAR COLUMNS
     * ====================================================================
     */
    public static final String TABLE_CAR = "car";
    public static final String COLUMN_CAR_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_CAR_NAME = "car_name";

 * ====================================================================
 * CREATING CAR TABLE
 * ====================================================================

public static final String DATABASE_CREATE_TABLE_CAR = "create table "
        + TABLE_CAR + "(" + COLUMN_CAR_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + COLUMN_CAR_NAME + " text );";
```

and here is repair table

```
 * ====================================================================
 * TABLE REPAIR COLUMNS
 * ====================================================================

public static final String TABLE_REPAIR = "repair";
public static final String COLUMN_REPAIR_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_REPAIR_DATE = "repair_date";
public static final String COLUMN_REPAIR_TYPE = "repair_type";
public static final String COLUMN_REPAIR_TOTAL_COST = "repair_total_cost";
public static final String COLUMN_REPAIR_LOCATION = "repair_location";
public static final String COLUMN_REPAIR_DETAILS = "repair_details";
public static final String COLUMN_REPAIR_CAR_ID = "car_id";


 * ====================================================================
 * CREATING REPAIR TABLE
 * ====================================================================

public static final String DATABASE_CREATE_TABLE_REPAIR = "create table "
        + TABLE_REPAIR + "(" + COLUMN_REPAIR_ID
        + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COLUMN_REPAIR_DATE
        + " text, " + COLUMN_REPAIR_TYPE + " text not null, "
        + COLUMN_REPAIR_TOTAL_COST + " number, " + COLUMN_REPAIR_DETAILS
        + " text not null, " + COLUMN_REPAIR_LOCATION + " text not null, " + COLUMN_REPAIR_CAR_ID
        + " integer, "  +
            "FOREIGN KEY (car_id) REFERENCES car(_id)" + " ON DELETE CASCADE );";
```

this is my main screen from where i select a car
[image]

here is my repair screen
[image]
here is the list of repair (which shows both car's repair data, i want the data of the car which i select)

[image]

i got the foreign key (car_id) null.

[image]

Comment: The frist thing You should do is to post some code, show us what You have tried and where the issue is.

Comment: `What should i do to store the records in table` Start by writing some code.

Comment: here is my code and screenshots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should to use ORMLite. It is so easy to use foreign keys and you don't write any sql queries. [link for ormlite](http://ormlite.com/). [Here is instruction to use (but in Russian)](http://habrahabr.ru/post/143431/)

Comment: thanks but actually this is my university project. and i'm bound to use SQLite :(

Comment: [https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html) look to 4.3. Answer is in here in my opinion.

Comment: bro! can u help me by making variable of column_car_id in my listview. each time i click on an item from listview it give me the same id in onItemselected() ?

Comment: in my opinion you are using ArrayAdapter for ListView. I suggest you to create a custom adapter which inherited from BaseAdapter and overwrite method getItemId

Comment: thanks bro for your time! actually i was being stupid. there is no problem in my database the point was that i wasn't putting the value of foreign key while entering other values. i had to pass the id and pass it to the activity meter meter and then cv.put( value of foreign key) .